# typeerror: Image input, 'imagePath' must be of type PIL.Image.Image in the input dict

Tags: python, object-detection, coreml, coremltools, mlmodel

Good morning everyone, I have my .mlmodel trained on license plates with size of 1920x1080.

My video test is also in the same resolution, when I am running the code it returns this error:

```
typeerror: Image input, 'imagePath' must be of type PIL.Image.Image in the input dict
```

The line is:

```
# Predict using Core ML model
output = model.predict({"imagePath": temp.name, "iouThreshold": 0.5, "confidenceThreshold": 0.5})
```

And the complete code is:

```
import cv2

model = coremltools.models.MLModel('NeuralVision.mlmodel')

video_path = 'anpr_video.mp4'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

# Desired size for the model input
new_width = 1920
new_height = 1080

# Process the video frame by frame
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Break the loop if we have reached the end of the video
    if not ret:
        break

    # Convert the frame to a PIL Image
    image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

    # Resize the image to the desired size
    resized_image = image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.LANCZOS)

    # Save the resized image as a temporary file
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png", delete=False) as temp:
        resized_image.save(temp.name)

        # Predict using Core ML model
        output = model.predict({"imagePath": temp.name, "iouThreshold": 0.5, "confidenceThreshold": 0.5})

    # Print the output
    print(output)

    # Display the frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

    # Break the loop if the user presses the 'q' key
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the video capture object and close all windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What I should try to change because at this point I don't know where it could be the problem

Comment: `coremltools`, `Image`, and `tempfile` are not defined.... what are these ?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example